# Getting my current location in android using GPS

Tags: android, gps

I am trying to get a current location using the GPS.

Given the following code:

```
    LocationManager manager = (LocationManager)this.
            getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Location loc = manager.getLastKnownLocation(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    loc=manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    double la=loc.getLatitude();
    double lon=loc.getLongitude();
```

When using the AVD emulator with defined fix coordinates, or when tested with my android smartphone, it does not work.

While in Android Studios trying to debug it with the emulator, it get stuck on the `loc.getLatitude`. Overall, at the end, I got a Java `RuntimeException` as shown below:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.social.gps/com.example.social.gps.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
        .
        .
        .
```

I guess its because the `loc` reference is null.

I have:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

in the manifest.

So how can I get it to work?

Comment: Post the rest of your stacktrace, please. `NullPointerException` here could mean anything - Context passed is null, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have DDMS prespective and send the latitude and longitude manually to the emulator.Because emulator doesn't retrieve the location status

Answer (score 0):

This is because your loc variable is null - it happens when there are no last location in the cache.

`getLastKnownLocation()` doesn't return the current location, it returns location obtained previously by your or some other app. To receive current location, you need to subscribe for location updates using `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates()`. That will start mentioned provider (GPS, Network or Passive) if it is enabled by user and send location updates via callback.

Comment: but I added locations to the emulator using the geo fix command, and according to the the android manuall, this is the way to get the location

Comment: to make `getLastKnownLocation()` work, some app need to obtain location previously. I suppose geo fix doesn't set last location directly, just envokes LocationManager update command. To recieve such updates and make them to be stored in the last location cache, you need to subscribe for them.

Comment: @user2162550 I mean, when you send location by geo fix, location manager sees that nobody is subscribed for updates and just drop it without updating its cache.